# Can I use "to partner" instead of "to partner with?"

Tags: phrases

We strategically chose these organizations to partner because...

Comment: https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/partner  See under **verb 1.1** *no object*

Answer (score 1):

In that context "with" would be superfluous, and potentially incorrect. "Partner" used transitively does not always require the preposition "with" with a direct object. However, in some transitive contexts "partner" does take "with" e.g. - "They took the decision to partner with another company".

The verb ***partner*** has two different transitive forms - senses 1 & 3 below. The first takes "with", the third does not. In between, the intransitive sense 2, also takes "with".

**It is a very subtle distinction between sense 1 (transitive - including "with") and sense 2 - intransitive.**

> **1. transitive. To make (a person) a partner; to join or associate with someone or something else. Usually in passive. a1616   Shakespeare
>   Cymbeline (1623) i. vi. 122   A Lady So faire,..to be partner'd With
>   Tomboyes.      1819   Blackwood's Edinb. Mag. 5 592   A respectable
>   accompaniment of lads and ‘lasses free’; with whom it is time to
>   partner ourselves on the green.**
>
> 1898   Times 10 June 11/4   Harry Vardon, who was partnered with Bob
>   Simpson.
>
> 1909   Westm. Gaz. 8 Feb. 12/4   Supposing a plus 3 man is partnered
>   with a steady player whose handicap is 8, the two as a foursome side
>   would be handicapped at 5.
>
> 1970   J. Earl How to choose Tuners & Amplifiers i. 14   Most
>   amplifiers can be partnered with a tuner of matching style and size.
>
> 2000   Petcare Jan. 3/3   Finally the dog is partnered with a disabled
>   person during a two-week intensive residential course.
>
> **2. intransitive. To associate or work as partners; to become partners, enter into partnership or a relationship.
>       a. With with. 1859   J. W. Loguen Rev. J. W. Loguen 79   He partnered with his brothers Carnes and Manasseth in the crime that
>   kidnapped her when a little child.**
>
> 1961   Webster's 3rd New Internat. Dict. Eng. Lang. (at cited word)
>   Him and me, we partnered once. A. B. Mayse.
>
> 1968   Globe & Mail (Toronto) 17 Feb. (Mag.) 9/2   In 1929 he
>   partnered with a U.S. businessman, Ben Raeburn, to publish a series of
>   ‘forbidden’ sex books.
>
> 1985   L. McMurtry Lonesome Dove (1986) xxiv. 222   It's odd I
>   partnered with a man like you.
>
> 2000   Daily Tel. 7 Mar. 39/4   Alba has partnered with Pace Micro
>   Technology, which manufactures set-top boxes for digital TV.
>
> ```
> **b. With up, off. 1982   Legal Times (Nexis) 4 Jan. 3   Former SEC and FERC enforcer Theodore Sonde..has partnered up with D.C.'s Cole &
> ```
>
> Corette.**
>
> 1991   P. Lewis Martial Arts 53   These advanced techniques involve
>   partnering up with a fellow student and following a step-by-step
>   routine of attack, defence and counter-attack.
>
> 1996   Washington Times (Nexis) 26 Sept. m4   We usually do a footwork
>   drill to Irish music... After that, we'll start partnering off, and
>   the students will create their own phrases or fights.
>
> 2001   National Post (Canada) 25 Aug. w2/1   She..explained that being
>   single in Toronto is most definitely over. ‘No one's doing it any
>   more. Everyone's partnering up for life.’
>
> **3. transitive. To be or act as the partner of; (spec. in Ballet) to lift or support (a dancer) (cf. partnering n. 2).**
>
> 1876   J. B. L. Warren Soldier of Fortune iii. iii. 268   You
>   partnered me, And raked the ashes up in our dull home.
>
> 1882   Daily Tel. 24 June   The Colonials had scored 192 for the loss
>   of four wickets,..on resuming Bonnor partnered Giffen.
>
> 1894   N. Brit. Daily Mail 4 Sept. 3   Golf... The Right Hon. A. J.
>   Balfour..had a couple of rounds, partnering Mr. A. M. Ross against Mr.
>   R. M. Harvey and Mr. Ben Sayers.
>
> 1955   Times 13 June 12/5   On Saturday night Miss Smythe had
>   partnered Flanagan to victory in the opening event of the Show.
>
> 1977   New Yorker 4 July 70/2   Charles Ward and Clark Tippet are
>   soloists who do not belong in the premier-danseur roles they have to
>   assume in order to partner Gregory or van Hamel.
>
> 1990   N.Y. Times 4 Feb. h9   It is no longer unusual to see women
>   partnering—hefting and carrying—men in modern dance.
>
> 2001   Terrorizer Sept. 16/2   Now partnered by vocalist Apollos,
>   Intra-Venus' recent sophomore effort ‘Irreverence’ continues their
>   masterly fusion of traditional goth aesthetics and contemporary
>   darkwave sounds.

(Oxford English Dictionary)